# Trying to Subscribe to a method that returns an Observable in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs-observables, rxjs-subscriptions

I have a method that returns an Observable:

```
clockOut(): Observable<boolean> {
    let isClockedOut = new Subject<boolean>();
    isClockedOut.next(false);

    // Some code to clock out and return x

    if (x === true) {
        isClockedOut.next(true);
    }

    return isClockedOut.asObservable();
}
```

And I'm calling/subscribing to the clockOut() method like so:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.clockOut().subscribe((didClockOut: boolean) => {
        if (didClockOut === true) {
            // Do stuff
        }
    });
}
```

The clockOut() method gets called, and the code inside clockOut() executes properly, but the code block after .subscribe is not being called. Almost like clockOut() isn't returning the Observable?

I'm new to Angular and I've not worked with Observables/Subjects much. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `subject` does not return old events to new subscriptions, you are triggering, next before returning the observable, so those events are not subscribed yet.

also, you don't have any need for `Subject` here since everything is synchronous.

if you want last event triggered you can use `BehaviorSubject` instead of `subject`

Comment: Ah! I used BehaviorSubject and it seems to work. Thanks.